# Dynamic code to addClass to an element specified in the link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a class to an element specified within my HTML from clicking on a button.

HTML:

```
<div id="servicenext"><a href="#nav2"><p class="four">next</p></a>
```

Script:

```
$('#servicenext a').click(function(){
     $('ul.navigation a').removeClass('active');
     $(*the div in the href*).addClass('active');
});
```

I'm hoping to have code that's dynamic. Basically it'll work by adding the class to any element specified in the `a` href.
This is because i have quite a handful of these and do not wish to code them individually.

EDIT:

Thanks James! that's great! 
But I do have to apologize, i was confused myself at what I was asking for!
What I'm actually looking to `addClass` to was actually the `li` in `ul.navigation a`

So if I'm thinking right, im trying to do this:

- by clicking onto the servicenext button,
- the code gets the `id` of the `div` in the `href`
- the `addClass` is applied to the `li` with the same `href`

I'm guessing there should be if else statements somewhere, forgive me, i'm not really a programmer.

the gibberish i came up with is:

```
$('#servicenext a').click(function(){
     $('ul.navigation a').removeClass('active');
     $($(this).attr("href").find($('ul.navigation li a').attr("href"))).addClass('active');
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Since the value of the `href` attribute is already a valid ID selector, you can simply use the value of the attribute:

```
$($(this).attr("href")).addClass('active');
```

Note that you have to get the actual attribute value. The native DOM property returns an actual URL, not just the value of the attribute.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/KtZ6z/1/).